# File uploads in Symfony 2 using sonata-project

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to upload a image in Symfony 2 from the backend using sonata-project. Challenge that i'm facing right now is to get the image inserted into the database table and uploaded to the specified path. I have given my upload folder writeable permissions. I am not sure what i am missing but here are the steps that i have taken.

```
class HomeEnumerate
{

// ...
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/houses';
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->house_picture ? null :   $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->house_picture;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->house_picture ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->house_picture;
}
```

}

I have edited my HomeEnumerate.orm.yml i have put in lifecycleCallbacks:

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ preUpload, setCreatedAtValue, setExpiresAtValue ]
    preUpdate: [ preUpload, setUpdatedAtValue ]
    postPersist: [ upload ]
    postUpdate: [ upload ]
    postRemove: [ removeUpload ]
```

After generate:entities I have edited my HomeEnumerate entity

```
class Job
{
// ...

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function preUpload()
{
     if (null !== $this->file) {
         $this->logo = uniqid().'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
     }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // If there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->logo);

    unset($this->file);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Can someone please help me uploading the files to the db and folder path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement some callbacks in your admin class, too. Actually, SonataAdminBundle has [a cookbook recipe on handling file uploads](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/cookbook/recipe_file_uploads.html). Hopefully, it should answer all of your questions.